# trouble compiling qpdf 5.1.3

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install `qpdf 5.1.3`. The default ubuntu version is `5.1.1`.

So I went to their Sourceforge page http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/ and downloaded the package. Then I did `./configure; make; make install`  , but it tells me:

```
configure: WARNING: unable to find required header zlib.h
configure: WARNING: unable to find required library z (or zlib)
configure: WARNING: unable to find required header pcre.h
configure: WARNING: unable to find required library pcre
configure: error: some required prerequisites were not found
```

So I need to find zlib and pcre. Any idea how? `sudo apt-get install` doesn't get me anywhere and the Ubuntu software center tells me I already have a package called zlib1g .

There are zlib and pcre files in the "external-libs" folder on the qpdf sourceforge page (link above), but I tried exporting both the folder and the individual files in the qpdf folder, with the exact same result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: run `make clean; ./autogen.sh; ./configure`

Comment: It looks like it works, but then qpdf is still 5.1.1;  and make; make install still shows the same error message

Comment: Please the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: And to be honest, your question was answered and you should accept the answer. Your current problem is a new one and you should ask a new question for this.

Comment: it still falls into "trouble installing qpdf 5.1.3" though?

Comment: lsb_release -a says:  No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: You need help, right? Then please stick to the rules of the game. **;)**

Comment: yeah, sure, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `zlib` with :

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

And `pcre` with :

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

Then try to compile again.

---

For the future ... if you are searching for packages in your system use `apt-cache search`:

```
apt-cache search pcre
libpcre3-dev - Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - development files
```

Comment: yeah, now the issue is different

Comment: Please edit your question with the new issue.

Comment: here, I just did (sorry I'm a bit slow, I'm new in here) (btw, do you know how to put those nifty grey areas around code?)

Comment: No problem. To format code, simply select your code and click the **{}** button. Refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for more help ;)