# trouble installing qpdf 5.1.3; unable to infer tagged configuration

Tags: bash, compiling, make

I'm trying to install qpdf 5.1.3. The default Ubuntu version is 5.1.1. (I have Ubuntu 14.04.3)

After a few tries (I did what was written here: [trouble compiling qpdf 5.1.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694678/trouble-installing-qpdf-5-1-3)), the end of the output tells me :

```
config.status: libqpdf/qpdf/qpdf-config.h is unchanged  
config.status: executing libtool commands  
/bin/bash ./libtool --quiet --mode=compile g++ -Wold-style-cast -Wall -MD -MF libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep -MP -Iinclude -Ilibqpdf  -c libqpdf/BitStream.cc -o libqpdf/build/BitStream.o; sed -e 's/\.o:/.lo:/' < libqpdf/build  /BitStream.tdep > libqpdf/build/BitStream.dep  
libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration  
libtool: compile: specify a tag with `--tag' 
/bin/bash: libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep: No such file or directory 
make: *** [libqpdf/build/BitStream.lo] Error 1 
/bin/bash ./libtool --quiet --mode=compile g++ -Wold-style-cast -Wall -MD -MF libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep -MP -Iinclude -Ilibqpdf  -c libqpdf/BitStream.cc -o libqpdf/build/BitStream.o; sed -e 's/\.o:/.lo:/' < libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep > libqpdf/build/BitStream.dep
libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: compile: specify a tag with `--tag'  
/bin/bash: libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep: No such file or directory  
make: *** [libqpdf/build/BitStream.lo] Error 1
```

After removing and re-exporting the archive anew, running  `./autogen.sh; ./configure; make`  gives me:

```
config.status: executing libtool commands  
sed -e 's:@PACKAGE_VERSION@:5.1.3:g' \  
        -e 's:@docdir@:/usr/local/share/doc/qpdf:g' \  
        < manual/qpdf.1.in > doc/qpdf.1  
sed -e 's:@PACKAGE_VERSION@:5.1.3:g' \  
        -e 's:@docdir@:/usr/local/share/doc/qpdf:g' \  
        < manual/fix-qdf.1.in > doc/fix-qdf.1  
sed -e 's:@PACKAGE_VERSION@:5.1.3:g' \  
        -e 's:@docdir@:/usr/local/share/doc/qpdf:g' \  
        < manual/zlib-flate.1.in > doc/zlib-flate.1  
/bin/bash ./libtool --quiet --mode=compile g++ -Wold-style-cast -Wall -MD -MF libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep -MP -Iinclude -Ilibqpdf  -c libqpdf/BitStream.cc -o libqpdf/build/BitStream.o; sed -e 's/\.o:/.lo:/' < libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep > libqpdf/build/BitStream.dep  
libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration  
libtool: compile: specify a tag with `--tag'  
/bin/bash: libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep: No such file or directory  
make: *** [libqpdf/build/BitStream.lo] Error 1
```

and running `g++ -Wold-style-cast -Wall -MD -MF libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep -MP -Iinclude -Ilibqpdf -c libqpdf/BitStream.cc -o libqpdf/build/BitStream.o` gives no output

Comment: *"after a few tries"* ... Did you unpack a fresh copy of the tarball after these failed attempts? Sometimes it helps to start with a 'clean' source tree.

Comment: remove the complete source folder `rm -r qpdf-5.1.3`, extract the archive again, run `./autogen.sh; ./configure; make`

Comment: I edited the post to include it

Comment: Why `make install`, first run `make`

Comment: btw, I use `qpdf --version ` to check if it worked

Comment: sorry, that was actually make, not make install

Comment: Run `g++ -Wold-style-cast -Wall -MD -MF libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep -MP -Iinclude -Ilibqpdf  -c libqpdf/BitStream.cc -o libqpdf/build/BitStream.o` and give me the output.

Comment: It didn't give me anything so I added `--verbose` at the end. I'll copy the ouput in the post just now

Comment: No output is great =)

Comment: Nice! I'm happy to hear that :)

Comment: I need a test. Install `libtool` from the Ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt-get install libtool-bin`. After that, run **exactly this** command: `libtool --quiet --mode=compile g++ -Wold-style-cast -Wall -MD -MF libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep -MP -Iinclude -Ilibqpdf  -c libqpdf/BitStream.cc -o libqpdf/build/BitStream.o; sed -e 's/\.o:/.lo:/' < libqpdf/build/BitStream.tdep > libqpdf/build/BitStream.dep`

Comment: no output. And libtool-bin didn't work (Package libtool-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package. [...] libtool) , so I installed libtool instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31182/discussion-between-a-b-and-fal).

Comment: Ok, we try to change the libtool binary: `rm libtool; ln -s /usr/bin/libtool libtool`. After that, run `make ` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is, that `./autogen.sh` had some problems. For interested readers, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31182/discussion-between-a-b-and-fal) is the chat.

1. Delete the source folder
2. Install the missing dependencies for `./autogen.sh`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install autoconf
   ```
3. Run the commands below inside the source folder.

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```